# Adding libtomcrypt and libtommath to my c++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am a **C#** developer, and spoiled rotten when it comes to references and dependencies. I am working on a small project now in **Visual C++** (`Visuial Studio 2017`), where I want to use the [**libtomcrypt** and **libtommath**](https://www.libtom.net/) libraries. I've created a small project and added the `2` projects to my solution:

[image: Add projects to solution]

**I have also added my includes:**

[image: Added Includes]

**And I added the dependencies:**

[image: Dependencies]

**However, I still can't build:**

```
Error   C1083   Cannot open include file: 'tomcrypt.h': No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what else I need to do to get the references working and the code to compile. Any pointers is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was building the project under x86. Once I changed it to x64, it built just fine.

Comment: The reason for this is the property page is per configuration. You need to select All or multiple configurations when adding the include directory path.

Comment: Aaaaargh!  Bitten once again by the #$&@ Visual Studio Project Properties dialog!  I have ALWAYS hated the way properties are handled for multiple build configurations (usually it's debug/release).  Someone really needs to get in there, tear that thing to shreds, and start over from scratch (MS: I'm available!).  It should have a way to define "common" properties and then provide a way to override/add/change certain properties for each configuration.  (This almost exists via "property sheet" files, but it's not easy/obvious.)

Answer (score 3):

The error message indicates that the compiler can't find the file `tomcrypt.h` while compiling one of your source files.  From the message I would guess that you have a line like the following in your source file:

```
#include <tomcrypt.h>
```

(...or perhaps with quotes instead of brackets.)  From your screenshot I can see that you've added "...\repos\libtomcrypt-develop\src\headers" to your include path.  Is the file `tomcrypt.h` found directly in that folder, or is it perhaps in a subfolder instead?

Your `#include` directive will basically append whatever path you give it to each entry in your include path when looking for the file, so if there are subfolders in between, you'll have to expand your `#include` directive to include those folders.

If this doesn't solve your problem, perhaps try posting the actual full path of where this header file exists on your filesystem, as well as your complete include path value!  (The full compiler command from the build log would be useful, as well as the complete error message(s) related to this source file.)

**Edit**:

The original poster posted a separate answer indicating that the actual problem was that the Visual Studio Project Properties were set correctly, but that he was accidentally trying to build a different Configuration. :(

Comment: Yes, `tomcrypt.h` is directly in the include path - I also updated the post with the command line. Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: What does the source file look like where you have the #include statement?

Comment: I've added my source example - You can also see the contexts of the include here https://github.com/libtom/libtomcrypt/blob/develop/src/headers/tomcrypt.h

Comment: That all looks good so far.  Can you copy/paste from the build log?  The entire command as it's actually executed when compiling your source file (which would include the preprocessor defines, the include path, the full path to the source file, etc.) AND the complete error message that follows.

Comment: Build log added